# Calculating Principal Components - PCA - Calculating Eigenvectors as PCs

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, principal-component-analysis

I've encountered difficulties while calculating (by hand) the principal components of the following covariance matrix:

$$\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} 4 & -\sqrt{3}\\ -\sqrt{3} & 2\end{bmatrix}$$

I know how to calculate the eigenvalues ($\lambda_1 = 5$, $\lambda_2 = 1$) but I'm confused after that. I have the solution but I can't reproduce it or do not know what happens there.

So, here is the solution:

> [image: Solution PC]

My questions are as follows.

1. How is the solution for each $\lambda$ calculated?
2. How do they come from the eigenvectors to the principal components? I thought the eigenvectors are already the principal components?

Would be nice if someone can explain me what is going on there, and maybe as detailed as possible and for non-mathematicians :) Cheers!

Comment: but question 1 you said how to do it, you said "I know how to calculate the eigenvalues"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after writing down your EVD decomposition that is
\begin{equation}
 \Sigma = UDU^T
\end{equation}
Notice that $U^T = U^{-1}$ because $\Sigma$ is symmetric, so we have that (as you mention that eigenvalues are)
\begin{equation}
 D = \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  0 & 5
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
and the second screenshot computes the eigenvectors (which i'm sure you know how to do:
\begin{equation}
 U = \begin{bmatrix}
  u_1 & u_2
 \end{bmatrix}
 =
 \frac{1}{2}
 \begin{bmatrix}
  -\sqrt{3} & 1 \\
  1 & \sqrt{3}
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Now let any vector $x = \begin{bmatrix}
 x_1 & x_2
\end{bmatrix}^T$ be given so 
\begin{equation}
 y 
 =
 \begin{bmatrix}
  y_1\\y_2
 \end{bmatrix}
 =
 Ux
 =
 \frac{1}{2}
 \begin{bmatrix}
  -\sqrt{3} & 1 \\
  1 & \sqrt{3}
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
  x_1 \\
  x_2
 \end{bmatrix}
 =
 \begin{bmatrix}
  -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x_1 + \frac{1}{2}x_2\\
  \frac{1}{2}x_1 + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} x_2
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I think I can follow a bit but I'm wondering why we have to multiply by 0.5 when we compute the eigenvector? Is that always the case? And if we would have for instance 3 eigenvectors, would it be still 0.5 or 1/3 ?

Comment: @Marl .. if $v$ is an eigenvector, then so is $\alpha v$, where $\alpha $ is a scalar. Usually, eigenvectors are normalized, that is $\alpha$ is chosen so that $ \Vert \alpha v \Vert^2 = 1$ so $\alpha = \frac{1}{\Vert  v \Vert^2}$. In your case for both eigenvectors, $\alpha = \sqrt{(\pm \sqrt{3})^2 + 1^2}= 2$

Comment: @Marl For this problem, we want unit eigenvectors so that $U$ is orthogonal ($U^{-1}=U^T$).